# Rotating Icons Using Javascript position

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, sass

i want to position items dynamically using javascript but i really don't know how to do this i am still learning javascript , i want to add for example 4 icons 1 in the top and 1 in the bottom and 1 in the left and right but using css when you need to add more items you have to add more css code and position statically , here is the code :

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
}

.container-circle {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.container-circle .container-circle-img {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.container-circle::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -3;
  left: -3;
  right: -3;
  bottom: -3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, red, blue, yellow, green);
  animation: rotate 3s linear infinite;
}

.container-circle-icons {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 60%;
  animation: rotate 10s linear infinite;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container-circle-icons .ico {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.container-circle-icons .ico1 {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -20%;
  left: 35%;
}

.container-circle-icons .ico2 {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -30%;
}

.container-circle-icons .ico3 {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 35%;
  bottom: -30%;
}

.container-circle-icons .ico4 {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -60%;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-circle">
  <img class="container-circle-img" src="picture.jpg" alt="pic1">
  <div class="container-circle-icons">
    <img src="icon1.png" class="ico ico1" alt="">
    <img src="icon2.png" class="ico ico2" alt="">
    <img src="icon3.png" class="ico ico3" alt="">
    <img src="icon4.png" class="ico ico4" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: my question is how can i position for example a circle then position an icon on the top and an icon for bottom and 1 for left and right using javascript without adding css code staticlly , because javascript can help with position dynamically it gets position absolute values and add icons in the right position without you calculate to add and scale icons every time you want to add more icons .

Comment: What do mean 'rotate'? Rotate to an angle or move between their positions?

Comment: move between their positions , i just want to know how can i position these icons with top bottom left right with javascript , and i will make them work rotating with css .

Answer (score 0):

The position of the elements will end up being dictated by the CSS, but if you want to add the elements dynamically and move them around, you can set that CSS using javascript.

Lets say you insert a new element with `id='test'`
You can dynamically change its position by doing this:

```
const newElement = document.getElementById('test');
element.style.left = '150%' // whatever value you want
element.style.top= '75px' // make sure you include units
```